# Multiple web fragments with the same res-ref-name

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, jndi, web.xml, web-fragment

1. What would happen if I have multiple web-fragments which declare `resource-ref`s with the same `res-ref-name` in case of:

   - The `resource-ref`s have the same `res-type`
   - The `resource-ref`s have different `res-type`
2. Also what would happen if there is a `resource-ref` with the same `res-ref-name` in the `web.xml` in case of:

   - The `resource-ref`s have the same `res-type`
   - The `resource-ref`s have different `res-type`

I'm looking for what the specs are saying and not "try it to find out".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Java Servlet Specification Version 3.1](https://java.net/downloads/servlet-spec/Final/servlet-3_1-final.pdf) has the following to say in §8.2.1:

> The requirements about name uniqueness that exist currently for a single web.xml also apply to the union of a web.xml and all applicable web-fragment.xml files.

and §14.4 says:

> The res-ref-name specifies the name of a resource manager connection factory reference. The name is a JNDI name relative to the java:comp/env context. The name must be unique within a deployment file.

Therefore your application should fail to deploy.